# Get textFieldShouldReturn to Apply to Two Textfields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm working on an app in **Swift 3** and have two separate `textfields` separated by a date picker (not sure if the date picker is relevant).

I want to use the `textFieldShouldReturn` to hide the keyboard when the user taps done after both `textfields`. However, it only hides the keyboard after the first text field and won't go away after the second one. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made your view controller the delegate for both text fields?

Comment: @Magnas No, how would I do that? I think that's the primary issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the view controller the delegate for both text fields, as @Magnas stated.

You can do this like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textField1.delegate = self
    self.textField2.delegate = self

}
```

For future reference, it helps to include code snippets in your question!

Comment: Don't forget to make sure your view controller conform to the delegate: class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate { }